# How to upload files to AWS S3 bucket from the react frontend

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

Hello I am trying to upload images from my react frontend but its unable to read the file in axios and the images are not being uploaded.

This is my code.

```
 <form onSubmit={Upload}>
        <input
          type='file'
          onChange={(e) => {
            generate(e.target.files);
          }}
        />
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
```

```
const generate = async (data) => {
    const payload = {
      entity: 'test',
      userId: '200',
      documentFileName: data[0].name,
      action: 'putObject',
    };
    console.log('DAATA', data[0].name);
    await api
      .generatePreSignedUrl(payload, token)
      .then((res) => {
        setUploadUrl(res.data.data);
        setImageData(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error', err);
      });
  };



 const Upload = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('IMAGEdata', imageData);
    console.log('URL', uploadUrl);
    let file = imageData[0];
    console.log('THIS IS FILE', file);
    console.log('FILENAME', file.name);
    console.log('FIELETYPE', file.type);
    var options = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': file.type,
      },
    };
    await axios
      .put(uploadUrl, file, options)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('Response from s3');
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert('ERROR ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      });
  };
```

Here imageUrl is the signed URL that I get from was to upload my files. I am successfully able to call the put request to upload the file but the image or file is not being read and uploaded.

This is the response when I am trying to look at the uploaded file.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>documents/ama/test/200/displaypicture.png</Key>
<RequestId>R7M63AHQKDNC6NH5</RequestId>
<HostId>3u8Jb8Ev4S1s/ODicL3Py4hvrvwKKOs/5zGxUEDYORfN1+U37Zx8PfYvIcGWUIAfeCqHpWqXd8o=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: You can try https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at the AWS SDK for JavaScript Developer Guide Version 3. There are examples that show how to upload photos to an Amazon S3 bucket.

[Uploading photos to Amazon S3 from a browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html)

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple way to use this node module to achieve this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aws-s3
https://medium.com/@steven_creates/uploading-files-to-s3-using-react-js-hooks-react-aws-s3-c4c0684f38b3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gBEc.png)

npm install --save react-aws-s3

Comment: note: article is behind an account-nag-wall requiring you to sign up to read the article.